# Having a method react to PropertyChanged in a DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, mvvm, properties

I have a DLL with a class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
It has a String Property who's setter trigger PropertyChanged.
This String is modified asynchronously "within" the DLL.
I can but do not wish to modify the behaviour of the DLL since i want to keep it as general and reusable as possible.
If i bind a field in my view to the property it updates fine.
In my Visual Studio solution i wish to keep it as MVVM as possible, not using any polling loops or timers.

What i want to add to the solution is a method that, in the same manner as the field, trigger whenever this property is updated. Is this possible and still keeping it within the MVVM pattern?

Comment: You might just manually attach a handler method to the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface that enforces the `PropertyChanged` event to be implemented. You may simply subscribe to this event to call a method:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.PropertyChanged += myClass_PropertyChanged;

...

public void myClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")
        DoWork();
}

public void DoWork()
{
    //Your functionality.
}
```

Comment: Is this an **explicit** way to do what the "Binding" does **implicitly**?

Comment: With this as a tremendously simplified representation, yes I do believe so.

Comment: If you mean they both use the `PropertyChanged` event. You might find the following articles interesting: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) & [Scott Logic](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html)